# Rails where clause not equal to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey folks trying to do a simple query where I find all records where a particular attribute is nil. In this case...

```
irb(main):009:0> Registration.where(:registration_cancellation_token != nil)
  Registration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `registrations`.* FROM `registrations` WHERE (1)
=> [#<Registration id: 1, orientation_id: 13, first_name: "mark", last_name: "Busta", email: "marklocklear@gmail.com", student_id: "3232333", phone: "3884448333", registration_cancellation_token: nil, registration_cancelled_at: nil, checked_in: false, created_at: "2014-02-20 13:46:31", updated_at: "2014-02-20 13:46:31">]
```

...but the query is returning all registrations. Any help appreciated...

Comment: Unfortunately you can not do it in a pretty way (at least not with `rails 3.2` and less)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Registration.where("registration_cancellation_token IS NOT NULL")`

Comment: Boom! You nailed it cuz! Thanks!

Comment: Patience little grasshopper. ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
Registration.where.not(registration_cancellation_token: nil)
```

This works for Rails 4